# How the get values defined in "setup" in groovy spock when testing SpringBoot web app?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, repository, spock

I am trying to save an entity into the database and use the returned primary column ID to search with and test with.

This is how I set up the test. First I save a default entity into the DB and the returned primary key I store in a variable (appId):

```
@Autowired
AppRepository appRepository

@Shared
Long appId
String appName = "mock application name"
String appCode = "mock application code"

def setup() {
    appId = saveNewApplication(appName, appCode) // this saves a new entity into the DB successfully and returns the new ID
}
```

This simple test works perfectly, I get the expected result:

```
def "test get application by id"() {
    when: "trying to get applications by id"
    AppEntity result = appRepository.get(appId)

    then: "no exception is thrown"
    noExceptionThrown()
    then: "response entity is returned"
    result
    result.id == appId // appId is not null here
    result.name == appName
    result.code == appCode
}
```

But when I want to test with "where" clause to avoid duplicates, it does not work:

```
@Unroll
def "test get application by id - present or not present"() {
    when: "trying to get applications by id"
    AppEntity result = appRepository.get(idToSearchWith)

    then: "no exception is thrown"
    noExceptionThrown()
    and: "response entity may returned"
    (result != null) == isPresent
    if (isPresent) {
        result.id == appId
        result.name == appName
        result.code == appCode
    }

    where: "possible scenarios"
    idToSearchWith | isPresent
    appId          | true // appId is null here
    -1L            | false
}
```

The first from the "where" fails because appId is null.

I guess this is because the first declaration is the "where" and only then comes the "setup".

But how could I resolve this kind of testing?

The only possible solution which I can imagine is that if I set the identity insert to off and I insert a specific pre-defined appId.

But what if I need to do more complex things to get a value which I want to use in the "where"?

Comment: try renaming `setup()` -> `setupSpec()`

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case I would suggest to have two separate tests.
I consider `if` inside tests to be a code smell, sometimes it may be necessary but most of the time it shows that you should split it into two separate tests. In this case it also solves your problem.

```
def "appRepository.get returns a result for a valid id"() {
    given:
    Long appId = saveNewApplication(appName, appCode)

    when: "trying to get applications by id"
    AppEntity result = appRepository.get(appId)

    then: "response entity is returned"
    result
    result.id == appId // appId is not null here
    result.name == appName
    result.code == appCode
}

def "appRepository.get returns null for an unknown id"() {
    expect: 
    appRepository.get(-1L) == null
}
```

If you mark your tests with `@Transactional`, then the database will be rolled back at the end of the test.

`noExceptionThrown()` is redundant in your case, it is generally implied and should only be used, if there are no other checks performed.

Comment: Yes, this is how I managed to do instead of my first idea. Thank you!